# How to disable Mac start on touchpad press?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad, shutdown

I have a MacBook pro 2019. It is a good machine, except apple changed a few things which I do not like and would like to revert.

Earlier version of Macbooks did not have this feature. Earlier, when MacBook is completely shutdown (not just that screen is all black but something is still running inside), click on touchpad would be disabled. This used to help me identify that my machine is completely shutdown or not.

But on the new MacBook starts up on any key press and touchpad click. If my Macbook is shutdown, and if I click on touchpad, it boots up. It has happened to me a few times with new MacBook that as soon as screen goes black I put the machine back in the bag and after some time when I open the bag, I find my machine to be very very hot because it did not shutdown completely and some process got stuck and kept draining the batter.

I see solution for disabling startup on Keypress but not on touchpad press. Any solution for that? Also any way to know if my machine has gracefully shutdown?

Comment: Duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349658/prevent-macbook-pro-from-turning-on-by-touching-trackpad?rq=1

Comment: Just have to know which is the "ANY" key...